# Render field in backend record form from plugin xml file

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, custom-component, fields, media-manager

I'm building a component with payment plugins and I need to display the plugins fields in the account form record.

The plugin xml fields section is

```
<fields name="params">
        <fieldset name="basic">
            <field name="paypal_email" type="email" default="" label="plg_mycomponent_paypal_email" description="plg_mycomponent_paypal_email_desc"  />
            <field name="paypal_image" type="media" default="" label="plg_mycomponent_paypal_image" description="plg_mycomponent_paypal_image_desc" filter="safehtml" />
        </fieldset>
    </fields>
```

I need to display the paypal_email and paypal_image fields in the account form and to have the possibility to save the values in account table.

How I can do that?

I try to achieve that with a "template" php file in the plugin to display the fields but it's not working.

Comment: Hi Jeremie, please add more details and try to clarify what you are trying to do. Personally I am confused by reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I applied [this tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin)

and now it's working.

I load an xml file in the form with plugin event that I fire in the view.html.php and bind the form. I also modify the account model functions "save" and "loadFormData" because I'm saving the values in JSON format.

the plugin event to load fields to form

```
function addParamsToForm($form, $data) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $option = $app->input->get('option');

    switch ($option) {
        case 'com_mycomponent' :
            if ($app->isClient('administrator')) {
                JForm::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
                $form->loadFile('params', true);
                foreach ($form->getFieldset('paypal') as $field) {
                    $form->bind($data["paypal"]);
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the /forms/params.xml file in the plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
<fields>
    <fieldset name="paypal">
        <field name="paypal_email" type="email" default="" label="plg_mycomponent_paypal_email" description="plg_mycomponent_paypal_email_desc"  />
        <field name="paypal_image" type="media" default="" label="plg_mycomponent_paypal_image" description="plg_mycomponent_paypal_image_desc" filter="safehtml" />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```